# Matlab image conversion jp2 to jpg

Tags: image, matlab, jpeg

I have a weird problem in matlab. I have code that takes in a directory of jp2 files and converts all of them to either tiff, png, or a jpg file. Then it puts these files in a new directory. The user can specify how big they want the file to be in terms of how many pixels are used (EX: 1:3:end is every three pixels). This code works perfectly for the png and tiff conversions.

With the jpg conversion there is no error whatsoever but when I go to click on the jpeg file in the new folder (which it does go to at least) It says "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large" I tried opening the pictures in other viewers but it said the same thing. All of the png and tiff pictures opened fine.

Some help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I noticed when I call imshow on the location of the jpeg file it actually does show up in matlab. It still does not show up in any image viewers though

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code?

Comment: Simplify your problem to debug it. Start with just one JP2 file that you know produces the bad JPEG. Convert it according to the methods in your full code and confirm that the issue is still present. Edit your question to provide the minimal runnable example code that demonstrates this issue so others can replicate it. Post the problem JP2 file online if possible.

Comment: So you've got code... that's great.  Can you show us what this code looks like?